# TCPDF ERROR: Unable to get the size of the image (in the header)

Tags: php

I see that many have asked the same question. I've seen them all but none helped me. I want to use an image in the header. This was working earlier, but now throwing up an error: TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image. Here is a part of my code:

```
define ('__ROOT__', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define ('K_PATH_IMAGES', '/images/');
require_once(__ROOT__.'/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetHeaderData("mylogo.jpg", "20", "Title", "Brief Description");
```

I have double checked that the image and folder names are correct. I tried the example as in https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/ and used MYPDF class, which too didn't work. I don't understand what is wrong. Please help!

By the way, the server has changed from http to https from the time the script was working.

Comment: Have you tried to specify full path of image?

Comment: Do you have an output after: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: ? Like a file path?

Comment: Yes, despite providing the full path, the error doesn't go away.

Answer (score 0):

First: coment the **define('K_PATH_IMAGES', '/images/');**

Second: move your images to tcpdf's folder. (So, move mylogo.jpg)

Why?

TCPDF will search for images in **TCPDF's folder** instead of an external folder called **image**

```
define ('__ROOT__', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
//define ('K_PATH_IMAGES', '/images/');
require_once(__ROOT__.'/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetHeaderData("mylogo.jpg", "20", "Title", "Brief Description");
```